# Google maps sdk nativescript: can i capture an image of the map?

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i use the maps plugin to show a map on my application. It works with this code:

```
onMapReady(event) {


    this.mapView = event.object;



    var marker = new Marker();
    marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(45.46, 9.18);
    marker.title = "Milano";
    marker.snippet = "Italia";
    marker.userData = { index: 1 };
    this.mapView.addMarker(marker);

    this.mapView.settings.zoomGesturesEnabled = false;
    this.mapView.settings.zoomControlsEnabled = false;
    this.mapView.settings.rotateGesturesEnabled = false;
    this.mapView.settings.scrollGesturesEnabled = false;
    this.mapView.settings.compassEnabled =[enter image description here][1] false;
    this.mapView.settings.indoorLevelPickerEnabled = false;


}
```

and the template:

```
<MapView #mapView row="0" col="0" [latitude]="latitude" visibility="visible" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"></MapView>
```

With this code i obtained a static view of the map ( static because i can't move the map) but when the map is loading there is a zoom until the zoom level that i defined. Can i remove this initial "zooming" ( the map camera move until my zoom level) ? or better can i show only an image of the map?

INFO:
nativescript 3.2.0 / tns-core-modules 3.1.1 / tns-android 3.2.0

nativescript-google-maps-sdk 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps take a screenshot of the map
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-screenshot